# How to disable a mouse scroll in Avalonia CalendarDatePicker?

Tags: avalonia

I need to disable the mouse scroll functionality of the CalendarDatePicker. So far, I have not found anywhere how I can do this.

```
<CalendarDatePicker FontWeight="SemiBold" DisplayDateStart="{Binding
                     Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat=dd/MMM/yyyy}" 
                    SelectedDate="{Binding ExpiredDate}" 
                    IsTodayHighlighted="True" BorderThickness="0" 
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent"  
                    Watermark="Выберите дату"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding !Status}"
                    Grid.Column="1"></CalendarDatePicker>
```

How can i do this?

I am not aware of the CalendarDatePicker property to disable mouse scroll functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just about to ask the same question! My first approach was to try handling the [PointerWheelChanged](https://reference.avaloniaui.net/api/Avalonia.Input/InputElement/FCBA17FD) event, and simply using `e.Handled = true;` to prevent the event from being fired. For some reason I couldn't get the event to trigger, but this might work for you.

I ended up using a button with a Calender in a flyout, which worked nicely.

```
 <Button Content="{Binding Date, StringFormat='\{0:d\}'}">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <Flyout>
            <Calendar SelectedDate="{Binding Date}"></Calendar>
        </Flyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

Comment: Also, I couldn't fire the trigger PointerWheelChanged

Comment: It's not quite what I expected, but it helped me! Thanks